# Probable memory leak in IE when using updatepanel and requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, memory, updatepanel

I have an extremely complex document generated by dynamic data. Recently we had an 'Out of Memory' issue arise from a user using IE8. However, it turns out all versions of IE seem to have a memory issue in this example. Any postback (partial or full) balloons IE memory usage by 2-50mb per postback. With enough usage, it's easy to balloon over 1GB of usage for a simple page (Chrome memory sits around 30mb).

I've simplified the code to quickly display the problem.

Created with Visual Studio 2008, .Net 3.5 (Tested in VS 2012, issue still present)

Aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IEMemLeak.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWebsite.IEMemLeak" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="True" ></asp:ScriptManager>
      <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>          
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>          
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebsite
{
  public partial class IEMemLeak : Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Button { ID = "PostbackButton", Text = "Click Me"});

      //This is where we'd pull dynamic controls from databased templates. simplified as a for loop to create a lot of controls (makes the mem issue really stand out)
      for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
      {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox {ID = "TextBox" + i, Text = "abc" + i, CausesValidation = true};
        RequiredFieldValidator requiredFieldValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator { ControlToValidate = "TextBox" + i};

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(requiredFieldValidator);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know this isn't the most elegant example, but I think it's enough for demonstration purposes.

Has anyone ever come across this error or a similar one (and managed a work around)?

Comment: how big is the page response which comes in to the browser? kbs.. mbs?

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: In my true application, it can be either. In this users case it was probably slightly under 1MB.

Comment: Have you indeed verified it hangs on the RequiredFieldValidator, as in he title? Emphasize that, and also be clear about the Image (because that's more likely to be a problem).

Comment: Without the requiredfieldvalidator the memory increase seems insignificant. It seems to grow eponentially with this combination. I'll pull the Imagebutton from the example since it doesn't seem to be entirely necessary.